# AE and Æ in document names

Tags: document-library, document, sharepoint-on-prem

We've got a small problem with file names in SP 2013. It's probably some SQL collation thing, but would like to hear if there's a way to solve it.

Example:

We have a document with the name TestAE.pdf in a doc lib, and if we try to upload another one with the name TestÆ.pdf SP prompts that the file already exists.

Æ is a danish special character. We don't have the same issue with oe and ø.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When uploading documents to SharePoint, it compares the file names of files with the same extension based on their Unicode.

By default SharePoint does the comparison culture-sensitive, where a Unicode value representing a precomposed character, in this case `Æ`, are considered equivalent to the sequence occurrence of `AE`.

<s>You should experience the same thing when uploading file names with the letter `Å` and `AA`.</s>

Why `Ø` and `OE` does not trigger the same error, may be because the Unicode for `Ø` are not considered equavalent to the occurrence of `OE`.

Comment: Thanks, actually AA and Å also works. Do you know if we can do anything to help it?

Comment: @MortenF Honestly I'm not aware of a SharePoint setting for this. Previously when I've run into this issue I've advised clients to stick to one or the other. This is unfortunately one of those barriers you will face where custom code is your only option (that I know of) to circumvent this behavior.